# Native Messaging "Specified native messaging host not found" debugging

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromium, chrome-native-messaging

I have an edge extension that communicates with a native application using NativeMessaging.

This works fine if in my native.json the 'path' object is absolute.

Based on microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/native-messaging?tabs=v3%2Cwindows)
Specifies the path to the native messaging host binary.

> On Windows devices, you can use relative paths to the directory that
> contains the native messaging host manifest file.

So now I am trying to build a path that is relative to my manifest.json and I am failing miserably as all I get in my browser is

> Specified native messaging host not found

So I am looking for a way to debug or see some internal logs from Edge to see what path is trying to access, is there a way I can achieve this? I am sure my path is wrong in a way... but I can't seem to figure out what and some logs  would be great.

From chromium documentation https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging/

I tried commands that I see here buy my log.txt file empty.

So my question is, is there a way where Edge(Chromium) ouputs "Accessing executable 'path'" or something like that, so I can see what is going on there?

I think I searched everything online that I could possibly could and this is my last hope, maybe someone else has a guide on how to debug this issue.

Comment: You say you're using "a path that is relative to my manifest.json", do you mean relative to your **extension manifest.json**? But the doc means "relative paths to the directory that contains the **native messaging host manifest** file", in your situation I think it should be relative to your **native.json**.  You could try to check again.

Comment: Can you please post that as an answer, it's been 2 days... 2 days of trying to debug this. Indeed it's relative to native.json and not manifest.json. I can't actually believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're using "a path that is relative to my manifest.json", do you mean relative to your **extension manifest.json**? But the doc means "relative paths to the directory that contains the **native messaging host manifest** file", in your situation I think it should be relative to your **native.json**. You could try to check again.